# how to operate typeperf on non-English versions of windows?

Tags: windows-7, cmd, cpu-usage

i found this nice log-creating command line:

```
    typeperf "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
```

so far it worked for me well on an English language version of Windows 7 (or similar).
when trying out the very same thing on a German language Windows 7 it simply did not work.

how can the same functionality be triggered with that tool on a German (or other language) Windows 7?

Comment: some hints on the problem might be addressed here - but it stops giving the hints, and not a full and working solution.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/25bc6907-cf2c-4dc8-8687-974b799ba754/powershell-ausgabesprache-umstellen?forum=powershell_de

Answer (score 0):

the best line so far for German windows is this:

```
    Get-Counter '\Prozessor(_Total)\Prozessorzeit (%)'
```

It has multi-line outputs with the value in question typically printed with a comma as decimal separator (in contrast to the English dot). for 100% there is no dot given. parsing the results down to the value looks a bit difficult.

having a more generic solution would still be more nice. the web page linked below helped me a bit in understanding what the key problem is.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/25bc6907-cf2c-4dc8-8687-974b799ba754/powershell-ausgabesprache-umstellen?forum=powershell_de

that far i am not sure if it's possible to make it truly generic using such helpers e.g. the keyword listing - but i am not that deep in what PS offers, rather i am skilled in cmd.exe.

Comment: the sub-linked article proposes a procedure using PS scripting. an ultimate generic solution is not provided - rather a mix from manual & automatic operations is presented.

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/19/querying-performance-counters-from-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps somehow further: you can find out the corresponding counter name in your language by comparing these registry keys.

English:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009\Counter
```

Current language:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\CurrentLanguage\Counter
```

Here you have the list of names and IDs as value, so you can match them and find out the right one.